# angular2 app in nginx:stable-alpine docker image tries to GET a sockjs URL when I bind host 8080 -> container 80, but not 80->80

Tags: nginx, docker, angular

As the question states, I have an angular 2 application bundled with webpack in an nginx docker image.  I run webpack and minify/chunk my modules, and add all my assets into the /usr/share/nginx/html directory.  I do not change the nginx.conf files or anything.  When I do a command such as:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -d app_nginx
```

And navigate to localhost, I get a reasonable looking log:

```
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:17:45:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1288 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:17:45:37 +0000] "GET /css/app.8335816ecce8c3fbf5c2.css HTTP/1.1" 200 3620 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:17:45:37 +0000] "GET /js/polyfills.8335816ecce8c3fbf5c2.js HTTP/1.1" 200 194181 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:17:45:37 +0000] "GET /js/app.8335816ecce8c3fbf5c2.js HTTP/1.1" 200 191859 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:17:45:37 +0000] "GET /css/app.8335816ecce8c3fbf5c2.css.map HTTP/1.1" 200 10799 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:17:45:37 +0000] "GET /js/vendor.8335816ecce8c3fbf5c2.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2840585 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:17:45:37 +0000] "GET /js/polyfills.8335816ecce8c3fbf5c2.js.map HTTP/1.1" 200 909488 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:17:45:38 +0000] "GET /js/app.8335816ecce8c3fbf5c2.js.map HTTP/1.1" 200 783837 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:17:45:38 +0000] "GET /js/vendor.8335816ecce8c3fbf5c2.js.map HTTP/1.1" 200 10331786 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:17:45:38 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 766 "http://localhost/todos" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
2016/08/02 17:51:02 [error] 5#5: *12 open()   "/usr/share/nginx/html/currentsetting.htm" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /currentsetting.htm HTTP/1.1", host: "10.25.114.169"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:17:51:02 +0000] "GET /currentsetting.htm HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "-" "-"
```

I'm not exactly sure what that second to last error line is, but I'm getting 200's on all my CSS, JS, etc.

When I do a command like:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -d app_nginx
```

I get much weirder log output:

```
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:18:18:57 +0000] "GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1470161937983 HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "http://localhost:8080/todos" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
2016/08/02 18:18:57 [error] 5#5: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/sockjs-node/info" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1470161937983 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/todos"
2016/08/02 18:19:03 [error] 5#5: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/sockjs-node/info" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1470161943983 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/todos"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:18:19:03 +0000] "GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1470161943983 HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "http://localhost:8080/todos" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
2016/08/02 18:19:09 [error] 5#5: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/sockjs-node/info" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1470161949988 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/todos"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:18:19:09 +0000] "GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1470161949988 HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "http://localhost:8080/todos" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:18:19:15 +0000] "GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1470161955991 HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "http://localhost:8080/todos" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
2016/08/02 18:19:15 [error] 5#5: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/sockjs-node/info" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1470161955991 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/todos"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:18:19:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:18:19:19 +0000] "GET    /js/vendor.8335816ecce8c3fbf5c2.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:18:19:19 +0000] "GET /js/polyfills.8335816ecce8c3fbf5c2.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:18:19:19 +0000] "GET /js/app.8335816ecce8c3fbf5c2.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:18:19:19 +0000] "GET /css/app.8335816ecce8c3fbf5c2.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
2016/08/02 18:19:21 [error] 5#5: *4 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/sockjs-node/info" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1470161961988 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/todos"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:18:19:21 +0000] "GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1470161961988 HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "http://localhost:8080/todos" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
2016/08/02 18:19:26 [error] 5#5: *4 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/sockjs-node/info" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1470161966988 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/todos"
10.0.2.2 - - [02/Aug/2016:18:19:26 +0000] "GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1470161966988 HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "http://localhost:8080/todos" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
2016/08/02 18:19:32 [error] 5#5: *4 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/sockjs-node/info" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1470161972989 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/todos"
```

Note I can see and interact with the webapp using either of these containers.  I'm not making any websocket calls that I know of.  This is all bundled, compiled typescript/html/css.  My question is:

1. I thought it would just work if I bound the host port 8080 to the container port 80, which nginx listens on.  Instead, it seems like it is trying to GET from localhost:8080.  I would expect it to just try to GET from localhost, like in the first log.